# Add custom fields on adding product in shopify

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

How to add some extra details while adding products?

Currently I am able to add Variant in Product which shows an input field for the product in product details page. But then, I require to add the same Variants for all products.

My Requirement was to add custom field, e.g. Weight, Height, Wood Type, Color  etc. that would appear for all products that are of category Table.

Is this possible some how?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by creating a new template for your product. You can find some documentation for manually configuration additional product options [here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products#get-customization-information-for-products).

Most merchants on Shopify use [apps](http://apps.shopify.com) to avoid manually configuring additional product options.

Comment: Can we master fields that can be applicable to all product in backend..

Answer (score 0):

A simple task for you would be to add the information using the API for metafields since you are saying they are to be added to all the products. More information on metafields API and liquid are in the links below

[Metafield Object](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield) and [Metafield API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/metafield)

If they are only a few products, you can give this app a spin - [ShopifyFD](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopifyfd-dashboard-tool/lffljkleilfpjlmcdnoaghhcbnemelge?hl=en)

If the different fields affect the price, create variants. Metafields can also be defined at variant level.

Answer (score 0):

Product metafields can be managed from the Shopify adminpanel directly. You don't need a third-party app or chrome extension anymore!

From the adminpage, go to settings (bottomleft corner) and go to Metafields. From there, you can add the metafields to the product and set the desired contenttype (inputfield, image upload, checkbox, etcetera)

You will need to provide a namespace and key, which you can refer to from the code template. For instance: setting the "namespace and key" field to my_custom_fields.somefield, you will be able to access it from the product template file (product.liquid) like so:
`{{ product.metafields.my_custom_fields.somefield }}` or, of course, assign it like so:
`{% assign myField = product.metafields.my_custom_fields.somefield %}`

The created metafields will appear on the product editpage at the bottom. No chrome extensions needed!!

Answer (score -1):

The accurate answer to your question is ***NO, You can't***

But, the good news is there are some apps to accomplish the result. [Here is one of the apps](https://apps.shopify.com/smart-meta-fields) which is free!